# Send mail in php with data in table(Mysql)

Tags: php, mysql, email, joomla

I need to send an email with the data that is in the mysql table. I am using joomla1.5.

```
  $dataarray = $this->getData(); // returns data from table
  $header = "<div> <table><tr></tr>";
  $body = "Here I need to add table data";
  $footer = "</table></div>";
  $mailer->setSubject('Mailing');
  $mailer->setBody($header.$body .$footer);
```

I dont how to do that. Please someone help me.

Thanks in advance.

vinay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the JUtility class to send the mail:

```
JUtility::sendMail($mailfrom, $fromname, $recipient, $subject, $message, true);
```

$recipient is the email address you're sending the mail to, and the last parameter is a flag indicating whether the email uses HTML or not ( true = uses HTML ).
However, if you have to send a lot of mails, it would be better to use the Joomla mailer instead of calling JUtility each time.

```
$mail =& JFactory::getMailer();

$mail->setSender(array($from, $fromname));
$mail->setSubject($subject);
$mail->setBody($body);
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->addRecipient($recipient);
$mail->Send();
```

I hope it helped!

**I'm editing, I forgot to mention how to work with your data**

To craft the body of the message, it would depend on how your data is returned.
If it's an associative array, you should do something like this:

```
$message = "Hello {$dataarray[ 'name' ]}, thank you for adding a comment to our article {$datarray[ 'article_title']}!";
```

If your "getData()" method is returning an object.. well in fact crafting the message is just building a string and filling it with your data.
For very large emails, I usually have a template like this:

```
Hello %%USERNAME%%, thank you for adding a comment to our article %%ARTICLE_TITLE%%!
```

And then what you should do is:

$message = file_get_contents( 'your_template.tpl' );
$search = array( "%%USERNAME%%", "%%ARTICLE_TITLE%%" );
$replace = array( $dataarray[ 'name' ], $dataarray[ 'article_title' ] );
$message = str_replace( $search, $replace, $message );

That's all!

Answer (score 0):

This is the way php mail function works.

```
<?php
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
?>
```

Now you need to get the values (i.e. message) from mysql tables.
You can use normal mysql commands to fetch those data and thereafter use the php mail function.

Comment: **Ok I got it cleared. Thanks for the reply Pankaj. My question was not about the mail function it was all about adding table contents to the variable.      I just used .= instead of =  .                                                                                                                                                                 $mailbody = $this->getWishlists($user->id);
  
  $body .= "<div> <table><tr></tr>";
  foreach($mailbody as $m){
     $body .= "<tr><td>$m->author</td>$m->title<td></td><td>$m->agegroup</td></tr>";
   };
  $body .= "</table></div>";**

Thanks again

Comment: Hi Vinay... good to know the problem has been resolved... I thought it was about mail function, and yes .= appends contents at end...